# Javascript regex replace in-string variable with actual variable value

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like `"category/[categoryName]/[amount]"` to become `"category/movies/all"` (replace "[variable-name]" with the value of the variable with the same name). I have this so far but I'm missing something:

```
let categoryName = "movies"; // example variable, set somewhere else
let amount = "all"; // example variable, set somewhere else
...
let searchUrl = "category/[categoryName]/[amount]"; // Set dynamically, could be any params
let regex = /\[(.+?)\]/ug;
searchUrl = searchUrl.replace(regex, window['$1']);
```

but the value of `searchUrl` just becomes "category/undefined/undefined".

Is what I'm trying to do even possible? Was that asked before and my question title is just malformed? I know how to do this with 2 regexes, first getting the variable names then looping in them and substituting. However I would like to do it with one "replace" only. Is that possible or I have to use 2 regexes?

Comment: i tried this one and it works: searchUrl = searchUrl.replace(regex, '$1'); (it returns "category/categoryName/all").. But i am not quite sure why do you use window['$1'] nor why it does not work

Comment: Sorry I forgot one crucial detail! I changed my question, where categoryName is supposed to have a value

Comment: then why not use: searchUrl = searchUrl.replace(regex, categoryName); ?

Comment: because "category/[categoryName]/all" is set dynamically, it could be something else than "categoryName"

Comment: duh.. of course.. forgive me, sometimes my brain just stops working.. I have done similar to this before, but i was using object, and so: let data = {
  categoryName: "movies" // example variable, set somewhere else
};

let searchUrl = "category/[categoryName]/all";
let regex = /\[(.+?)\]/ug;
searchUrl = searchUrl.replace(regex, function(match, p1) {
  return data[p1];
});
console.log(searchUrl);

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly for this to work as dynamically as you state you will have to do the following

```
// example variable, you need to use var so its 
// available on the window otherwise this will not work
var categoryName = "movies"; 
...
let searchUrl = "category/[categoryName]/all";
let regex = /\[(.+?)\]/ug;
let variableName = searchUrl.match(regex)[0];
searchUrl = searchUrl.replace(regex, window['variableName']);
```

Your dynamic variable will have to be stored globally for this work!

Comment: My fault for not being precise enough. I know I can do it with 2 regex calls, but I would like to do it with only one call, a one-liner. I updated my question to be more precise, just wondering if this is possible. Still upvoted your answer as it's relevant to my original one.

Answer (score 0):

You're so close! What you have now tries to replace `[categoryName]` with the global variable `$1`, which doesn't exist. What you want is to use `searchUrl.replace(regex, categoryName)`, assuming `categoryName` is dynamically set with the correct category.

Comment: Thanks friend! Not exactly what I'm looking for though, I updated my question ;)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that with `.replace` you can enter multiple 'replacers', so you could say `str.replace(regex, replacer1, replacer2, replacer3...)`. Alternatively, you can pass a function to replace a matched value each time one is found.

I just modified your code to:

```
let categoryName = "movies"; // example variable, set somewhere else
let amount = "all"; // example variable, set somewhere else

// previous answer suggestion
// let replacers = [categoryName, amount];

let searchUrl = "category/[categoryName]/[amount]"; // Set dynamically, could be any params
let regex = /\[(.+?)\]/gu;
let replacers = searchUrl.match(regex).map( m => m.replace(/\[|\]/g,''));
searchUrl = searchUrl.replace(regex, () => { let val = eval(replacers.shift()); return val; });

output => "category/movies/all"
```

Since your regex is global, it continues to find matches but since there is only 1 replacer in your original code, it replaces the match with that replacer.

i.e. `categories/undefined/undefined` (using `searchUrl.replace(regex, window['$1']);`)

You may want to put your replacers into an array. Then with each match, use a function to replace the match with the value stored in the array, as shown in my example above.

**Note:** This example works for 2 matches only.

Hope this helps.

[MDN - Specifying a function as a parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter)

Comment: Yeah I was hoping to have a X number of variables and that the javascript would just parse ANYTHING between [ ] then find the corresponding variable, but it doesn't seem to be possible and it looks like I will have to use a loop with matches then replace manually unfortunately

Comment: the replacers array could have values in pushed into the depending the number of matches. A way you could do it is use `searchUrl.match(regex).map( m => m.replace(/\[|\]/g,''))` to get the matched results, then when using `.replace` replace those values using the function I provided.

Comment: *Added eval to function call